# InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

[image]

I am unable to detect the problem. When I remove admin panel routes from the middle ware auth group it works really fine. But with that routes it through this exception.

Here is my routes file.

```
   Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){


        Route::post('/signin','userController@postSignIn')->name("signin");
     });

My controller function is :

     public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
        $email = $request['email'];
        $user = User::where("email",$email)->first();

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']]))
        {
            if ($user['verified'] == 1){
                if ($user['role'] == 2) {
                    return redirect()->route('dashboardd');

                }
                else if($user['role'] == 0 && $user['blocked'] == 1 ){
                    $message = 'Your account has been blocked by admin';
                    return redirect()->back()->with('message',$message);

                }else if($user['role'] == 1 && $user['blocked'] == 1 ){
                    $message = 'Your account has been blocked by admin';
                    return redirect()->back()->with('message',$message);
                }
                else{
                    return redirect()->route('news-feed');
//                return view('frontend.layouts.user_login_layout',compact('posts','comments','keywords','regular'));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'Account not verified! Verify Email to activate your account';
                return redirect()->route('home')->with('message',$message);
            }

        }else{
            $message = 'Wrong Credentials , Try Again !  ';
            return redirect()->back()->with('message',$message);
        }
    }
```

These routes cause the problem . which are related to admin panel.
I have the same user table for admins and users. When I remove admin panel routes from the group user can login perfectly. but when I add these routes user can't login nor the admin.

```
    //admin-panel routes

Route::get('importExport', 'ExcelImportController@importExport');
Route::post('importExcel', 'ExcelImportController@importExcel');
Route::post('/logicsubmit','AdminController@logicsubmit')->name("logicsubmit");
Route::get('/RegularUser','AdminController@Regulars')->name("RegularUser");
Route::get('/Company','AdminController@Companies')->name("Company");
Route::post('/signup','userController@userSignUp')->name("signup");
Route::post('/companysignup','CompanyController@companySignUp')->name("companysignup");
Route::get('/logout','userController@logout')->name("logout");
Route::get('/dashboardd','AdminController@index')->name("dashboardd");
Route::get('/admit','AdminController@admit')->name("admit");
Route::get('/admin','AdminController@admin')->name("admin");
Route::get('/admins','AdminController@admins')->name("admins");

Route::get('/lock', 'AdminController@lock')->name("lock");
Route::post('/adminsignup','AdminController@AdminSignUp')->name("adminsignup");
Route::get('/view/{id}','AdminController@ViewUser')->name("view");
Route::get('/block/{id}','AdminController@blockUser')->name("block");
Route::get('/unblock/{id}','AdminController@unblockUser')->name("unblock");
Route::get('/delete/{id}','AdminController@deleteUser')->name("delete");
Route::get('/Addkeywords','AdminController@Addkeywords')->name("Addkeywords");
Route::post('/addword','AdminController@addword')->name("addword");
Route::get('/editword/{id}','AdminController@editword')->name("editword");
Route::get('/deleteword/{id}','AdminController@deleteword')->name("deleteword");
Route::post('/updateword/{id}','AdminController@updateword')->name("updateword");

//end of admin-panel routes
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ? Also, highlight the part which is causing issue.(admin routes as u mentioned)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @jaysingkar I updated my question as you mentioned.

Comment: @halfer Ok Thanks

Comment: @DevTaabi do you have any route named `login` in `routes.php` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you're using `route('login')` somewhere in your code (probably a view) but you don't have a route with name `login`.

Renaming `signin` to `login` will probably do.

```
Route::post('/signin','userController@postSignIn')->name("login");
```

Or go through code and replace all calls to route `route('login')` to `route('signin')`

Comment: When I change signin to login , it gives this error MethodNotAllowedHttpException at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php (line 238)

Comment: You will need to replace this route with your `GET` route that returns the login view.

Comment: Here's what you need to do: go through project and look for every reference to route named `login`. If it's in a form that posts to `POST` method, you change it to point to `signin`. If it is referenced in any other way (link, GET form...) you change it to whichever route returns the login view (it's not clear from your naming conventions, so I cant help you here).

Answer (score 0):

As you said when you remove auth middleware it works fine, the reason behind is 'auth' looking for authenticated routes that you can see by using `php artisan route:list` and if you use 'login' instead of  '/signin' route it will work fine.So please rename your '/signin' route to auth's 'login', cause it is pre-defined.

Comment: yes I am using signin route instead of login , but it works fine when I remove admin routes

Comment: when you doing signin internally it calls login route. so that can you rename it with login or you can add additional route as Route::post('login','userController@postSignIn');

Comment: When I change signin to login , it gives this error MethodNotAllowedHttpException at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)

Comment: Please change method to 'any'.

Comment: I don't think it will be good idea to change it to `any`. If DevTabi is using the POST request, it should work with `POST`

Comment: @jaysingkar agree with you because it is not working with any.

Comment: @DevTaabi can you post the stack trace of your current error, that might me helpfull

Comment: there is no such error occurs now , but it redirects me back to login page when I enter email and password

Comment: I  replace this route with your GET route that returns the login view as @devk mentioned in his comment